# Why node spawn() returns "undefined" at the beginning

Tags: node.js

Using Node's [spawn()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) function always returns "undefined" at the beginning, like in the following real example:

> undefined M text.txt M text_2.txt

This is the command `git status --porcelain` on a testing repository, this same command executed on the command line interface shows *(command included)*:

> $ git status --porcelain
>
> M text.txt
>
> M text_2.txt

The `spawn()` events are written like this:

```
  spawn.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
  spawn.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');

  spawn.stdout.on('data', function(d){ 
    data += d;
  });
  spawn.stderr.on('data', function(e){
    err += e;  
  });

  spawn.on('exit', function(){
    callback(err, data);
  });
```

Why is `spawn()` returning "undefined" at the beginning and how do I solve it?

Comment: Can you reduce the problem down to a [minimum and complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: How was the actual problem related to git?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Happy-trigger tag, fixed, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never declared or initialized `data`.
Therefore, it starts as `undefined`, and you're concatenating to that.